# Omit repeated values in CSV file with csvsimple

Tags: csv

I want to use the csvsimple package to turn a CSV file into a set of paragraphs, using the value of column 1 as a subsubsection header.

I can't see from the documentation any way to do an action only on first occurrence of a value. Is this possible with csvsimple?

```
COUNTRY,INST,ADDR,PHONE
US,Dept of Justice,Washington DC,123-456/7890
US,Dept of Education,Seattle WA,234-567/8910
UK,Minitrue,London WC,123 456 7890
UK,Miniluv,London EC,234 567 8910
```

This should generate something like:

```
\subsubsection{US}
Dept of Justice: Washington DC\\Phone 123-456/7890\par
Dept of Education: Seattle WA\\Phone 234-567/8910\par
\subsubsection{UK}
Minitrue: London WC\\Phone 123 456 7890\par
Miniluv: London EC\\Phone 234 567 8910\par
```

Is this possible? I was hoping to avoid the complexity of the datatool package, wonderful though it is.

Answer (score 5):

When processing the data you can test whether `\COUNTRY` has changed, e.g. with the `ifthen` package. `address.csv` is your sample data.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\newcommand\COUNTRYlast{}
\newcommand\doaddress%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\COUNTRY}{\COUNTRYlast}}%
     {}%
     {\subsubsection{\COUNTRY}%
      \edef\COUNTRYlast{\COUNTRY}%
     }%
   \INST: \ADDR\\Phone \PHONE\par
  }

\parindent0ex
\parskip3pt plus1pt minus 1pt

\begin{document}
\csvreader[head to column names]{address.csv}{}{\doaddress}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

Comment: Indeed I can; many thanks for the example. This mechanism would be a good enhancement...